# How to use a jar file as a library in a maven project

Tags: maven

So I have a library which I want to use, and I have it inside of a folder called "lib",
I'm working in maven so I put this in my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.worldborder</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldborder</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/WorldBorder.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Doing this allows me to write code which uses said library, but when I build the jar it gives me a no class def found error when using, when I use mvn clean install, I do get a warning when I build,

```
Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for me.acidviper:ViperUHC:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.worldborder:worldborder:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/src/lib/WorldBorder.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 85, column 25
It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

I'm a complete noob when it comes to maven, so I don't understand how to fix this error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I faced the same issue. To solve that I installed that jar directly into my local .m2 repository.

```html
mvn install:install-file
          -Dfile=/path/to/jar
          -DgroupId=org.worldborder
          -DartifactId=worldborder
          -Dversion=1.0.0
          -Dpackaging=jar
```

then if you are using spring boot you can use plugin like `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. It creates a complete jar for your application with all of it's dependencies